# If $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=100$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$, find the maximum possible product $(a_1)(a_2)(a_3)...(a_n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=100$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$,
>   find the maximum possible product $(a_1)(a_2)(a_3)...(a_n)$

So we could have:

$9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16=100$

or we could have:

$2+6+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15=100$

There is unlimited choices, so how would i be able to find the maximum possible product.

Comment: The $a_i$ can also be negative?

Comment: i would guess so since its in the integer group.

Comment: Then your product is unbounded.

Comment: We should not allow negatives, for then for most $n$ there will not be a max.

Comment: If $n$ is allowed to vary, nothing bigger than $4$ should be used, and $4$ is kind of useless too.

Comment: If $a_i>0$, the AM-GM inequality gives
$$
\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdots a_n}\leq\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n} = \frac{100}n\\
a_1\cdots a_n\leq \left(\frac{100}{n}\right)^n
$$
which has maximum at [$n = 100/e\approx 36.8$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximise+%28100%2Fn%29%5En). The above inequality is known to be equal if and only if all $a_i$ are equal, which would mean $a_i = e$ for all $i$. Of course, the fact that you're only limited to an integer number of $a_i$'s, and they can only be integers makes this a bit more difficult, but this _should_ tell you where to start looking for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For positive integers, where $n$ is not fixed, consider what you can do if there is a large $a_r$ to increase the product (think about what might make a large component). Then investigate how to maximise the product of small terms - e.g. what do you do to increase the product if one of the factors is $1$? Do a bit of experimenting and come back when you can show your work.

Answer (score 1):

As you allow negative integers and do not limit the number of terms one can see that given a summation $a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n=100$ with product of $a_i$'s $N$, a positive number, we can insert 4 more terms $10+40 -20-30$ which does not change the total but product gets multiplied by a factor of $24000$. So there is no upper bound, as we can continue this process indefinitely.

(I suppose you have no condition that the terms be distinct).